# Authentication_Unauthorized while fetching list of applications in AAD

Tags: azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am trying to get list of applications registered in AAD via PowerShell.

I got into my tenant successfully using `Connect-AzureAD`. But when I'm running `Get-AzureADApplication`, I'm getting error like below:

```
Get-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing GetApplications 
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found.
RequestId: 28b83872-c29b-423a-9870-ed2ad714f597
DateTimeStamp: Sat, 25 Jun 2022 1:35:23 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADApplication
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADApplication], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetApplication
```

What does `User was not found` message mean?

I have Global Admin role and  I tried elevating my access too that gives me access to all. But still I'm facing the same error.

Can anyone help me out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **The error **`'User not found`'** usually occurs if you are trying to retrieve info of one tenant by connecting wrong(different) tenant or tenant that does not exist.**

Please check the **TenantDomain** you are getting in the response while executing `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran `Connect-AzureAD` cmdlet and logged in with personal Microsoft account, I got blank under **TenantDomain** that means it does not exist.

I got the same error when I executed **`Get-AzureADApplication`** after that like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, try running **`Connect-AzAccount`** first and include ***TenantId*** that you got in response while executing **`Connect-AzureAD`** cmdlet like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId 'your_tenant_id'
Get-AzureADApplication
```

I got the list of **Azure AD applications** successfully after running above script like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[powershell - Authentication_Unauthorized, User Not Found - answered by **JoyWang**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139119/get-azuredomain-getazureaduser-etc-return-authentication-unauthorized-user-no)